# Home Office Rent Expense Payment via C-Corp

Tags: united-states, taxes, credit-card, small-business, irs

I am a 1 person incorporated C-Corp software development company. (Although, I currently usually do not use the C-corp for most checks and contracts which just go straight to me as an individual.)

I am considering using my business credit card to pay for my monthly apartment rent, where 90% of it is used as my office. 10% is a tiny bedroom, which I am considering paying back my business account the "sublet" difference. Effectively, this means that I still expense 90%.

Am I simplifying systems? Are there any complications that may arise from this?

Would the IRS still be okay with this?

Comment: I suspect the IRS won't believe that you use all of your apartment except for a tiny bedroom **exclusively** for business.

Comment: Kitchen?  Bathroom?  90% is entirely unbelievable.

Comment: Well it's between 80 and 90%. it's one of those city apartments with a tiny bedroom+full bath and large living area and external full bathroom

Comment: Kitchen usage - I'm usually on business calls or reviewing client documents while making/eating breakfast

Comment: @ina: I don't think that's sufficient.  You have to use an area exclusively for business for it to count as a home office.

Comment: How do you define exclusively for business though? What if I'm literally on calls or reviewing documents during all meals / even while toasting bread